# Как добавить класс в соседние элементы родителя

Tags: jquery

Есть item, в нем `content` и `slide`. Как при нажатии на `.more` в `content`, с помощью jQuery, добавить класс в `slide`?

```js
//Не работает. Надо - при нажатии на 'more' в 's-services-content' добавлять класс в '.s-services-slide' и убирать при повторном нажатии.

$(".more").click(function() {
  $(this).find('s-services-slide').toggleClass('s-services-slide-show', [1000])
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="s-services-item" style="background-image: url(img/ourServices/1.jpg);">
    <div class="s-services-content">
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="h3">Designing is the cool love for.</h3>
        <p>Our most popular service is our Virtual Receptionist. We know that sometimes it’s something and you middle most this job was posted less than five minutes ago, and we think it’s a good match for you. If you submit a proposal now, you’ll be one
          of the first candidates. You may even catch the client while they’re still online.</p>
        <span class="more">Know more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="s-services-slide">
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="h3">Designing is the cool love for.</h3>
        <p>Our most popular service is our Virtual Receptionist. We know that sometimes it’s something and you middle most this job was posted less than five minutes ago, and we think it’s a good match for you. If you submit a proposal now, you’ll be one
          of the first candidates. You may even catch the client while they’re still online.</p>
        <span class="more">Know more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
//Доработал, большое спасибо MedvedevDev

$(".more").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.s-services-content').siblings('.s-services-slide').addClass('s-services-slide-show');
  $(this).closest('.s-services-slide').removeClass('s-services-slide-show');
});
```

Comment: селектор в find - должен быть css селектором, в css перед классом ставится точка:  `.find('.s-services-slide')` сейчас же он ищет **элементы** `<s-services-slide></s-services-slide>`

Comment: Спасибо, но класс так и не присвоился, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в том, что **внутри** `<span class="more">` нет элементов с классом `s-services-slide`

Comment: судя по всему тебе нужен [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) вместо find

Comment: Сделайте то, что рекомендует Grundy - это поможет решить вашу проблему

Comment: вторым параметром в toggleClass передается условие. [1000] всегда будет отдавать false (класс применяться не будет), для закрепления напишу как должно выглядеть $(this).closest('.s-services-slide').toggleClass('.s-services-slide-show')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как мы заведомо знаем, что нужный нам блок (`.s-services‌​-slide`) является сестринским элементом для родителя (`.s-services‌​-content`) нашей кнопки (`.more`), то:

```
$(this).closest('.s-services-content') // ищем предка по селектору
  .siblings('.s-services‌​-slide') // ищем соседние элементы по селектору
  .toggleClass‌​('.s-service‌​s-slid‌​e-show') // добавляем/убираем класс
```